# multiple annotates are not working properly

Tags: django, django-queryset

Using multiple annotate queries giving unexpected results.

When I use annotate separately, it works fine.

```
event_queryset = OrderItemTable.objects.annotate(days=Sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(f_date_ord, l_date, unit='Day')*F(
     'prev_order_items__qty')/30, filter=filter), sales=Sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(f_date_sale, l_date, unit='Day')*F(
     'sales_order_items__qty')/30), rating = Cast(F('sales')/F('days'), FloatField(2)))
```

or

```
event_queryset = OrderItemTable.objects.annotate(days=Sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(f_date_ord, l_date, unit='Day')*F(
     'prev_order_items__qty')/30, filter=filter)).annotate(sales=Sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(f_date_sale, l_date, unit='Day')*F(
     'sales_order_items__qty')/30)).annotate(rating = Cast(F('sales')/F('days'), FloatField(2)))
```

In both queries, **days** variable is giving wrong values for some items. **Sales** is fine. And if I do this:

```
event_queryset_days = OrderItemTable.objects.annotate(days=Sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(f_date_ord, l_date, unit='Day')*F(
      'prev_order_items__qty')/30, filter=filter))

event_queryset_sales = OrderItemTable.objects.annotate(sales=Sum(TIMESTAMPDIFF(f_date_sale, l_date, unit='Day')*F(
     'sales_order_items__qty')/30)
```

Both give correct values. Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong.

**Or how can calculate rating if I use separate queries for days and sales.**

Comment: If you join on two tables, the two will act as a "multiplier" of each other.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, can I calculate rating by separate querysets for days and sales.

Comment: yes. It might even be (sometimes) faster, since you avoid the double join that could result in a huge amount of rows.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, can you suggest something?